# How can recive completely XMLHttpRequest from external webpage

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, phantomjs

when i call XMLHttpRequest with browser its show a result that are different every time,and seems not completely  receive data . for that i use Phantomjs for calling this request , but i cant get full of respond request, for that i use below code , but it not work and like browser call if request it's have different result every time .

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 5000;

page.open("http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfodata.aspx?i=9536587154100457&c=57+", function() {
    var ans=page.content;
    ans=ans.split(",");
    allnemads.push(ans);
    page.close();
});
```

how i can get completely  of this request ?
EDIT:
some of headers on request are :

```
Accept:text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__qca=P0-1512129452-1383575171205; ASP.NET_SessionId=0bzykf45ydyr2ovzfou0pd55
If-Modified-Since:Wed, 14 May 2014 07:11:02 GMT
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

how can set this parameter ?

Comment: What does not work? Where is allnemads defined?

Comment: It could be that the web service requires additional HTTP headers to be sent such as X-Requested-With to fake an AJAX request. You should inspect the HTTP headers and/or POST data sent with the request from Fiddler. Then you can mimic the request exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It can be the case that the service looks for legitimacy of the client making the request. To solve that, dump the data that you are getting without any assumptions about ","  being there in it, and see what it says. better yet, render the page with `page.render()` to debug.

Depending up on what you see, you may want to change `User-Agent`, `X-Request-With`, `referrer`, and few other headers fields in the request. You can match it with the request being sent from the browser, by checking it out in the network tab in Chrome inspector.

Comment: can help me for addential header or user-agent for correct recive request ... in chorme i see below information

Comment: some headers added too question ... how can i set that ? @vinit

Comment: check this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/). just copy the default User-agent, from the browser where the site works. Don't change the User-agent of your browser, unless you want to. For Other headers, open network tab and click on the packet in question.